# C# program reports "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, database, indexing

May I ask, how can I get error for this? It is so confusing. I get bug like this and I try to fix, but it does not work at all. I'm just a beginner.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Schedule : Form
    {
        public Schedule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=Payroll;User Id=root;password=''");
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        int tc = 0;
        private void Schedule_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datagrid();
            fillsched();

        }
        public void datagrid()
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from employee where Pstatus='Active'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            con.Close();
        }
        public void fillsched()
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from updateschedule ", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int data = dr.GetInt32("empSched");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(data);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        public void getsched()
        {

            if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), out tc))
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from updateschedule where empSched=@empSched ", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empSched", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = tc;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox2.Text = dr["TimeIn"].ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = dr["TimeOut"].ToString();
                    label5.Text = tc.ToString();//to pass the data in the combobox1
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        public void view()
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getsched();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {

                view();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insert();
            insertempsched();
        }
        public void insert()
        {


                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO schedule (empSchedID,empID,empIN,empOut)VALUES(@empSchedID,@empID,@empIn,@EmpOut)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empSchedID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = label5.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empIn", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox2.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empOut", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
                execnonquery(cmd, "Data Inserted");

        }
        public void insertempsched()
        {

                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update employee set empSched=empSched where empID=@empID", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empSchedID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = label5.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

        }
        public void execnonquery(MySqlCommand sqc, string mymsg)
        {
            con.Open();
            if (sqc.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(mymsg);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Query not Executed");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of code there, try narrowing down your problem to a small piece of code and making your question more clear in order to get effective answers.

Comment: i dont know where is conflic but ill try many times and but my tryhard code cannot answer that  i think my faul is on combobox indexes sorry for being a noob coder

Comment: Your post amounts to "This is some buggy code I wrote.  Please fix it".  At least tell us where the error is!  There are tens of thousands of similar posts here which ought givbe your the information/knowledge to fix it.

Comment: When it fails, Visual Studio tells you *exactly* where the problem is

Comment: ok ill try to find sirs

Comment: There are [several likely duplicates on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Index+was+outside+the+bounds+of+the+array); indeed, you would have seen these when typing your title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index was outside the bounds of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526484/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array)

Answer (score 1):

"Index was outside the bounds of the array" in c# always indicates that you are trying to get values based on column index number or row index number from datagrid or datatables or arrays and column or row does not exist at that position or index.

I think you are getting error at following line which exists in "view" method.

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Also to catch the errors it's a good practice to use try catch blocks in all the methods.

You can modify your method like this

```
public void view()
{
         try
        {
                 textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```